# Azure BlobTrigger is firing > 5 times for each new blob

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

The following trigger removes exif data from blobs (which are images) after they are uploaded to azure storage. The problem is that the blob trigger fires at least 5 times for each blob.

In the trigger the blob is updated by writing a new stream of data to it. I had assumed that [blob receipts](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-bindings-storage-blob?tabs=csharp#trigger---blob-receipts) would prevent further firing of the blob trigger against this blob.

```
[FunctionName("ExifDataPurge")]
public async System.Threading.Tasks.Task RunAsync(
    [BlobTrigger("container/{name}.{extension}", Connection = "")]CloudBlockBlob image,
    string name,
    string extension,
    string blobTrigger,
    ILogger log)
{
    log.LogInformation($"C# Blob trigger function Processed blob\n Name:{name}");

    try
    {
        var memoryStream = new MemoryStream();
        await image.DownloadToStreamAsync(memoryStream);
        memoryStream.Position = 0;
        using (Image largeImage = Image.Load(memoryStream))
        {
            if (largeImage.Metadata.ExifProfile != null)
            {
                //strip the exif data from the image. 
                for (int i = 0; i < largeImage.Metadata.ExifProfile.Values.Count; i++)
                {
                    largeImage.Metadata.ExifProfile.RemoveValue(largeImage.Metadata.ExifProfile.Values[i].Tag);
                }

                var exifStrippedImage = new MemoryStream();
                largeImage.Save(exifStrippedImage, new SixLabors.ImageSharp.Formats.Jpeg.JpegEncoder());
                exifStrippedImage.Position = 0;

                await image.UploadFromStreamAsync(exifStrippedImage);
            }
        }
    }
    catch (UnknownImageFormatException unknownImageFormatException)
    {
        log.LogInformation($"Blob is not a valid Image : {name}.{extension}");
    }
}
```

Comment: You are modify your trigger-blob  `await image.UploadFromStreamAsync(exifStrippedImage);`

So it's fired again

Comment: @MarkusMeyer That's my assumption too, but shouldn't the receipt prevent that?

Comment: Like mentioned in the receipt, you also have to check the `ETag`. Please have a look here. This might work for you: [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784094/cycling-azure-function-blob-trigger](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44784094/cycling-azure-function-blob-trigger) @Nattras

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So I've addressed this by storing a Status in metadata against the blob as it's processed.

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/blobs/storage-blob-container-properties-metadata

The trigger then contains a guard to check for the metadata.

```
if (image.Metadata.ContainsKey("Status") && image.Metadata["Status"] == "Processed")
{
    //an subsequent processing for the blob will enter this block. 
    log.LogInformation($"blob: {name} has already been processed");
}
else
{
     //first time triggered for this blob
     image.Metadata.Add("Status", "Processed");
     await image.SetMetadataAsync();
}
```

The other answers pointed me in the right direction. I think it is more correct to use the metadata. Storing an ETag elsewhere seems redundant when we can store metadata. The use of "CacheControl" seems like too much of a hack, other developers might be confused as to what and why I have done it.

Answer (score 2):

Triggers are handled in such a way that they track which blobs have been processed by storing receipts in container **`azure-webjobs-hosts`**. Any blob not having a receipt, or an old receipt (based on blob ETag) will be processed (or reprocessed).

since you are calling  **`await image.UploadFromStreamAsync(exifStrippedImage);`** it gets triggered (assuming its not been processed)

Comment: are you saying that the ETag changes if I uploaded new data into an existing blob?

Answer (score 2):

When you call `await image.UploadFromStreamAsync(exifStrippedImage);`, it will update blob so the blob function will trigger again.

You can try to check the existing [`CacheControl`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cdn/cdn-manage-expiration-of-blob-content#setting-cache-control-headers-by-using-net) property on the blob to not update it if it has been updated to break the loop.

```
// Set the CacheControl property to expire in 1 hour (3600 seconds)
blob.Properties.CacheControl = "max-age=3600";
```